Tag synonym: [verb-object-compounds] and [separable-verbs]
These two tags verb-object-compounds and separable-verbs identify actually the same thing.
However I can't propose the tag synonym myself, because I don't have 5 total score on those tags. It seems the only active user who can is Tang Ho (I just upvoted his only answer to a total of 5). Or an all-powerful moderator.
Do you agree? Shall we go ahead and synonymize the two tags?

It seems this would be a worthwhile synonym too.  (Instead of, say, simply retagging the small number of questions.)

(When it comes down to it, tags are long overdue for an overhaul: there's still meta tags like [intermediate] and [advanced], tags like [phrase-meaning] which are a subset of [meaning], the [mandarin], [simplified-chinese], and [word] tags which basically function as [random-question] tags, etc.)

I don't have 5 total scores on the 'verb-object-compounds' tag

Which tag do you want to remain?  (I suggest keeping [separable-verbs].)

@Becky李蓓 yes [separable-verbs] seems a more widely recognized term

There, I did it.
It's a tiny, easily reversible change [and it seems rather obvious to me], so I don't think there's any point dilly dallying on this.
(If anyone thinks this is a mistake, let me know please.)

I also edited the tag wiki to make it more succinct, and changed the example to show separation:

Separable verbs (or: verb-object compounds) are verbs that can be separated, such as 睡觉 within 睡一个好觉.

